# Cross domain jQuery ajax request doesn't respond correctly

Tags: jquery

I'm using an Ajax call with jQuery for calling a PHP script with some paramaters to another server.
So the Ajax call is made by server1 and the PHP file called is on the server2.
When I call the "success" method, the variable passed to the function is empty!
the PHP script don't do nothing exept for echoing a string (I'm on testing:)).
So the variable is still empty. I try to move the php file to the server1 where the Ajax call was made and works perfect. So is a cross server problem.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks

---

After reading the tutorial posted below I find this plugin, 
http://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js
I'm trying it and seems to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cross-server requests are a security issue (see [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). btw you can use JSON  to workaround this, check this [useful article](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) to see how.